# Метод бисекций и простых итераций C++

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Само задание: методом деления отрезка пополам и простых итераций для N значений погрешности e `(0,1; 0,01;0,001;..1e-N, 1≤N≤10)` вычислить значение корня для двух заданных функций на отрезке [A, B] = (0,2) и вывести их в виде таблицы (для каждой функции отдельную)

Функция 1: `1/(1,2tg(x)+sqrt(х+1))-х`; примерный корень: `0,52055`

Функция 2: `(sin⁡x+cos⁡x)^2/(33,5^2)^2/3+sqrt(3/7)-х;` примерный корень: `0,846395`

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как преобразовать первую функцию для метода деления отрезка пополам и вторую для метода простых итераций.

Также написал два метода, но не уверен, что правильно.

```
//Метод деления отрезка пополам
double bisekcii(double a,double b,double e,int i,int j, int N, double (*f)(double)){
    double c;
    i=0;//Счетчик итераций
    e=1/pow(10,j);//Погрешность
    while(fabs(b-a)>=e){      //продолжать поиск корня пока не достинута заданная точность
        c=(a+b)/2;        //делим промежуток пополам
        if((f(a))*(f(c))<=0)  //в зависимости от знака
            b=c;            //двигаемся к одному
        else
            a=c; //или другому концу промежутка
    i++;
    }
    printf("%14.*lf|",j,e); //Погрешность выводится с точностью j знаков после .
    printf("%4d|", i); //Число итераций метод I
    return (a+b)/2.0;   //Вернуть найденный корень уравнения
}


//Метод простых итераций
double iteraсii(double a,double b,double e,int i,int j,int N, double (*func)(double)){
   i=0;            // double (*func)(double)) указатель на фуккцию (один параметр типа double и результат double)
   e=1/pow(10,j);
   b=(a+b)/2;//значение начального приближения
   while(fabs(b-a)>=e){ //продолжать поиск корня пока не достинута заданная точность
      b=a;
      a=func(b);//Следующее приближение
      i++;
   }
   printf("%5d|", i); //Число итераций
   return b ;       // Вернуть найденный корень
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ощущение, что со второй функцией вы что-то не так написали, потому что указанный вами корень - не верен.

Я бы писал проще:

```
double bisekcii(double a, double b, double e, int& i, double (*f)(double))
{
    i = 0;
    double fa = f(a), fb = f(b);
    assert(fa*fb < 0);
    while(b-a >= e)
    {
        double c=(a+b)/2;
        if (double fc = f(c); fa*fc <= 0)
            b=c;
        else
            a=c;
        i++;
    }
    return (a+b)/2.0;
}


double iteracii(double x, double e, int& i, double (*f)(double))
{
    i=0;

    double y = f(x);

    while(fabs(y-x) >=e )
    {
        x = y;
        y = f(x);
        i++;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Для деления пополам ничего преобразовывать не нужно; для простых итераций уравнение приводится к виду `x == f(x)`, при этом на `f(x)` накладываются определенные условия (прочтите учебник), но в вашем варианте можно просто вытащить `-x` на другую сторону равенства :)

```
double f1(double x)
{
    return 1/(1.2*tan(x)+sqrt(x+1))-x;
}

double f2(double x)
{
    double z = (sin(x)+cos(x));
    z = z*z;

    return z*z/(33.5*33.5*33.5*33.5)/3+sqrt(3./7);
}
```

Полная программа: https://ideone.com/arvjl5

Обратите внимание, что второе уравнение решено двумя разными методами, корень совпадает (но не с указанным вами).

Ну, а цикл по разным погрешностям напишите уж сами - только без этого ужаса с `pow`:

```
for(double e = 1; e > 1e-11; e /= 10)
```

И еще раз напоминаю - пересмотрите свою вторую функцию, вы явно неверно переписали ее из задания!

Comment: Прошу прощения, действительно неправильно переписал вторую функцию. Вот правильный вариант: ```(sin⁡x+cos⁡x)^2/(33,5^(2/3))+sqrt(3/7)-х; ```

Comment: Нет, все равно не легче: https://ideone.com/HaVd4Y

Comment: Тогда так: https://prnt.sc/11kwsn8

Comment: А, да, я ошибся в коде. См. https://ideone.com/HaVd4Y еще раз.

Comment: Извините, не могли бы Вы подсказать, почему на тесте ```N=10, a=0.5, b=0.6 ``` программа неправильно считает итерации для обоих методов? https://onlinegdb.com/H1p9yt_Uu

Comment: Для второй функции и бисекции понятно: корень находится вне указанного диапазона. Бисекция для первой функции и простые итерации для второй вполне работают: https://ideone.com/mjnj4Q

Comment: Я про количество выполненных итераций для каждого из методов. Например, для теста ```N=10, a=0.5 b=0.6``` для обоих методов программа выводит количество итераций 0, хотя должно вывести 1 https://prnt.sc/11l4b52

Comment: Ну какие итерации, если у вас диапазон уже равен погрешности? :)